# Color code not working in with background:>#ff5a00<

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am following this: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

To change to color of the action bar with appCompat. here is my code:

** res/Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>'

<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="background">#ff5a00</item>
</style>
```

**Res/Values-v11/Styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="android:background">#ff5a00</item>
</style>
```

in The first part of code #ff5a00 is giving me the error: Cannot resolve symbol #ff5a00

but in the second part for api over 11 the code is working fine with the Android in front.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<resources>`, write

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

And put your color in color.xml

```
<item name="background">@color/red</item>
```

and for values-v11:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
```